# Checkbox creation using clone() method of jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I my form I have duplicate checkbox like

```
<input type="checkbox" name="todayDimensionStones[].isIssued" id="isIssued"  value="Yes"/>
```

I am creating another checkbox using above using clone() method using jquery.The checkbox box is created successfully.But when I checked and submit the form containing the newly created checkbox and retrieve the value of newly created checkbox,it seems to be empty ie ''. What I to do solve this problem.If any have an idea ,please share with me

Comment: Don't use duplicate IDs, the jQuery API specifically warns you about this. http://api.jquery.com/clone/ "Note: Using .clone() has the side-effect of producing elements with duplicate id attributes, which are supposed to be unique. Where possible, it is recommended to avoid cloning elements with this attribute or using class attributes as identifiers instead."

Comment: Have you confirmed via DOM inspector that the element that gets inserted has the appropriate attribute values? I.e., is it just on submit that it gets munged, is it munged when it's inserted into the document, or is it munged as soon as it's cloned?

Comment: value attribute may be missing.But I have set the value using $(this).val="Yes".But again it is ''

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the attribute `name`
or you have to add `[]` at the end of the `name`.

If you send two inputs with the same name without `[]` at he end, php gives you the last one only.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone stumbles about this: value attribute is probably missing. Set it manually after cloning:

On the cloned element with some checkboxes do:

```
$clone.find(':checkbox').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('checked','checked')
});
```

Thats on IE9. See https://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/10550